# Varbinary(max) too large to read in ASP.NET Core

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, file-upload, varbinarymax

In the database I use a column of datatype `varbinary(max)` to save an image, but when I load the image, I get a timeout.

```
public async Task<byte[]> UploadImage(IFormFile req)
{
    using var ms = new MemoryStream(16 * 1024);
    await req.CopyToAsync(ms);

    byte[] result = ms.ToArray();

    ms.Close();
    ms.Dispose();

    return result;
}

public string RetrieveImage(byte[] data)
{
    return string.Format("data:image/png;base64,{0}", Convert.ToBase64String(data, 0, data.Length));
}
```

I tried to find out but it keeps giving error

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
> Win32Exception: The wait operation timed out.
> Unknown location
>
> SqlException: Execution Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, bool breakConnection, Action wrapCloseInAction)

Data displayed in SQL Server is `<Binary data>`

Comment: There's no `binary(max)` datatype in SQL Server - I assume you're really using `varbinary(max)` ...

Comment: There's no database code in your snippet? Nor is the whole stack trace included